# mix monotouch and Obj-C or C++

Tags: c++, objective-c, mono, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I got another crazy idea: why do I want to create a static lib in XCode, then create monotouch bindings for it then linking this lib with monotouch project. That would be much easier to have all the sources in a single project...

I'm trying to have Obj-C, or C or even C++ sources right in monotouch project compiled all-together. But apparently I got no luck with that. I can't make C code to compile from monodevelop.

Does anybody tried this approach? what are pros and cons (if it is possible)?

Answer (score 0):

You're right that you can have several projects, in different languages, inside a single MonoDevelop solution.

However you'll still need to create bindings to access **non** .NET code (e.g. C/C++) and data from the main (C#) project solution.

So having a single solution can be a *bit* simpler in many cases but it won't be **a lot** simpler - unless you're using .NET for **every** projects.

Note: there are now *binding solutions* templates in MonoDevelop that can make binding non-.NET code simpler. That's more likely yo help you.

Comment: Can you provide a link to any more information on what these "binding solution templates" are?  I'm very interested in MonoTouch bindings at the moment and would love to read more.

Comment: yes, I'm trying to use .NET for every project. do you mind to share a link to the binding solution templates you mentioned?

Comment: what I meant originally is I don't mind to create bindings. The thing I'd like to achieve is to have all the sources in a single project. So I'd prefer to customize "build rules" for different source types without using static libs